# solving ODE with neural network by fixed point theorem

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, ode

I want to solve ODE

[image]

with neural network and compare this with true solution $u(x) = x$.

**Method**

- Build a neural network, say $v(x;w)$, where $x$ is 1-d input and $w$ is weight.
- Set loss function as

[image]

- Use either adam or sgd to minimize the loss

**Question**

In theory, this shall converge to true solution by fixed point theorem. 
But I do not know how to implement it, especially how to set the loss function with tensorflow gradient.

**Code**

Here is some code up to the point I stuck with.

```
#creat training data
x_train = np.arange(10)/10. #the derivatives will be taken at these pts.
y_train = np.zeros(x_train.shape) #we do not need it indeed.
# model for the candidate function
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, input_shape=(1,), use_bias=True),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

Any opinion will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the docs, any guides or tutorials?

Comment: i searched but no docs have found in this